# How to force delete a file in Windows 7? 

Tags: windows-7

I know this question is asked but there is no solution for me. I tried unlocker, fileassassin, lockhunter and commnd prompt to delete file but it didn't work.

Comment: What is the file?

Comment: What type of file you want to delete?

Comment: @Robotnik video file which is not complete, 7 dose not recognize file type

Comment: is it possible the program still has it open? did the program crash when building the video? if you boot into safe mode can you delete it there?

Comment: i download video from youtube by idm i recognize later that file name with <:> will will not work now i have many files i also try after end of explorer.exe

Comment: Have you tried this [FileDeletor](http://download.cnet.com/File-Deleter/3000-2248_4-10359339.html)

Comment: I don't know about the other utilities, but I know that _unlocker_ will try various ways to delete, and as a last resort will put a file deletion command in the queue for the next reboot. So my question is: Have you rebooted since trying unlocker?

Comment: @Heptite yes I tried

Comment: @SpK FileDeletor did not work

Comment: Delete the folder that contains the file, with `rmdir /q /s`. If that doesn't work, try `rm` using `cygwin`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boot your system with a Linux live CD then you should be able to delete it.

If you don't have a CD burner you can try using a flash drive with [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can reboot the system to force delete a file, here are the steps:

Step1: Press Win logo key + R and then type: MSConfig.

Step2: Now, turn to Boot tab and then tick Safe Boot from Boot Options section.

Step3: Once you click on the OK button, the system will ask you to restart the system.

After successfully booting into Safe Mode, launch File Explorer and try to delete unwanted files.

Comment: https://www.r-datarecovery.com/force-delete-a-file-folder.html